# Excel VBA - Extract lines containing a particular name from multiple text files

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to extract text lines from text files to excel, but only if they contain a certain name within the line. Ignoring the rest of the lines.

I'm currently working with a large number of text files containing standardized information for certain products. Each file has the same list of products, but information from different dates. I've put together some code that pulls in each row from the text files contained with the directory, and includes them together in a single excel spreadsheet.

What I would like to change is for the code to only copy over text lines containing a certain name within the line like "Large Cap Index". The rest of the data can be ignored. This is attempting to cut down on the amount of time it takes to pull in the data, since only about 5% of the lines within each text file is needed.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range
    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\crowe12\Desktop\Projects\CRSP\Test")
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    For Each file In folder.Files
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine
            Items = Split(TextLine, "|")
            cl.Value = folder & "\" & file.Name
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = Items(i)
            Next
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        FileText.Close
    Next file
    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test each line using something like this:

```
Dim x As Long
x = 1
For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
    If Items(i) Like "*your value here*" Then
        cl.Offset(0, x).Value = Items(i) '<< this offsets to the right: 
                                         '   did you mean to offset down?
        x = x + 1
    End If

Next
```

Comment: Yes, I need to offset down.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the line, why dont you check if the text that you want is present on it or not and then skip it based on the check

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range
Dim textToSkip as String: textToSkip="Large Cap Index"
' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\crowe12\Desktop\Projects\CRSP\Test")
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
For Each file In folder.Files
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine
        'You can covert this to lowercase before hand to match ignoring case
        If Instr(1,TextLine,textToSkip) > 1 Then
         Items = Split(TextLine, "|")
         cl.Value = folder & "\" & file.Name
         For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
          cl.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = Items(i)
         Next
         Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Loop
    FileText.Close
Next file
Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

I did not change much in your code except the condition

Comment: @C.Rowe Great. Please upvote the answer if that worked